# XML output feed

Tags: php, xml

I am totally new to this subject. I have a feed created to display our products. But I can't figure out how can I limit the number of characters to display in name tag.

```
$product_title = $productDescription[2]['name'] ? html_entity_decode($productDescription[2]['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') : '';
                        $output .= '<item_name ><![CDATA['.$product_title.']]></item_name>'."\n";
                        $description = html_entity_decode($productDescription[2]['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't fully understand the question, but if you want just to limit product_title into item_name you can use this code

```
$desired_length = 100; // or some other value
$product_title = $productDescription[2]['name'] ? html_entity_decode($productDescription[2]['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') : '';
$product_title = substr($product_title, 0, $desired_length);
$output .= '<item_name ><![CDATA['.$product_title.']]></item_name>'."\n";
$description = html_entity_decode($productDescription[2]['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```